# Variadic template couples

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

is it possible to write variadic couples of templates? Something like:

```
template<typename<typename A, typename B>...>
class A : public std::tuple<A<B>...>
{
};
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: You'd need to elaborate on your idea. It's hard to understand what's your goal

Comment: My ultimate goal is to write a generic way to deal with multiple association relashionships (I did not find much on this subject on google but if you know a good way to do it I would love it!). So this is just a test to know if I could write something like: class AnyClass : public IAmAssociatedTo<ASingleRelation<A>, AnotherSingleRelation<B>, AMultipleRelation<C>>

Comment: Show why a garden variety variadic template doesn't suit you.

Comment: There are several workarounds depending on **what** you actually need to do inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using type list i got this to compile:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
using namespace std;

template <typename ...Args>
struct type_list
{};

template<typename B, template <typename> class ...A>
class test;

template<typename ...B, template <typename> class ...A>
class test<type_list<B...>, A...>: tuple<A<B>...>
{};

template<typename T> class t1{};
template<typename T> class t2{};
template<typename T> class t3{};

int main() {
    auto t = test<type_list<int, double, char>, t1, t2, t3>();
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know, why you need this, but it should make what you want.

Comment: I don't know either what I can do with this, I just explore several possibilities :) This answer is perfect for what I asked so thank you very much!